# Looping foreach for always several times

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, controller

I always have 12 `$new['period_??']`. For now, I write these code 12 times after I declare a `$new['period_??']`. Is there any way to make it simpler?

```
          foreach ($new ['period_10'] as $item) { $po_10th [] = $item -> po_id ; }
          $new ['uni_10'] = array_unique($po_10th) ;
          foreach ($new ['uni_10'] as $po_id) {
            $po = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_po_by_id (md5($po_id)) ;
            $pos_10 [] = $po ['po_id'] ;
            $currency10 [] = $po ['currency'] ;
          }
          $cur_pos_10 = array_unique($currency10) ;
          foreach ($cur_pos_10 as $currency) {
            $new ['po_arr_10'] = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_pos_with_curr ($pos_10,$currency) ;
            $total_price = array () ;
            $curren = array () ;
              foreach ($new ['po_arr_10'] as $key) {
                $total_price [] = $key -> total_line_price ;
                $curren [] = $key -> currency ;
              }
              $new ['total_n_curr10'] [] = array_merge(array(array_sum($total_price)),array_unique($curren)) ;
          }
```

This is the hard reality i've been done!

```
    $new ['period_1'] = $periodic_items [0] ; $new ['frek_1'] = $frek [0] ;
      $new ['period_2'] = $periodic_items [1] ; $new ['frek_2'] = $frek [1] ;

      $new ['period_3'] = $periodic_items [2] ; $new ['frek_3'] = $frek [2] ;
      $new ['period_4'] = $periodic_items [3] ; $new ['frek_4'] = $frek [3] ;

      $new ['period_5'] = $periodic_items [4] ; $new ['frek_5'] = $frek [4] ;
      $new ['period_6'] = $periodic_items [5] ; $new ['frek_6'] = $frek [5] ;

      $new ['period_7'] = $periodic_items [6] ; $new ['frek_7'] = $frek [6] ;
      $new ['period_8'] = $periodic_items [7] ; $new ['frek_8'] = $frek [7] ;

      $new ['period_9'] = $periodic_items [8] ; $new ['frek_9'] = $frek [8] ;
      $new ['period_10'] = $periodic_items [9] ; $new ['frek_10'] = $frek [9] ;
        foreach ($new ['period_10'] as $item) { $po_10th [] = $item -> po_id ; }
          $new ['uni_10'] = array_unique($po_10th) ;
          foreach ($new ['uni_10'] as $po_id) {
            $po = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_po_by_id (md5($po_id)) ;
            $pos_10 [] = $po ['po_id'] ;
            $currency10 [] = $po ['currency'] ;
          }
          $cur_pos_10 = array_unique($currency10) ;
          foreach ($cur_pos_10 as $currency) {
            $new ['po_arr_10'] = $this -> model_prcsys -> get_pos_with_curr ($pos_10,$currency) ;
            $total_price = array () ;
            $curren = array () ;
              foreach ($new ['po_arr_10'] as $key) {
                $total_price [] = $key -> total_line_price ;
                $curren [] = $key -> currency ;
              }
              $new ['total_n_curr10'] [] = array_merge(array(array_sum($total_price)),array_unique($curren)) ;
          }

      $new ['period_11'] = $periodic_items [10] ; $new ['frek_11'] = $frek [10] ;
      $new ['period_12'] = $periodic_items [11] ; $new ['frek_12'] = $frek [11] ;
```

Can anyone help me make it simpler? It always loops 12 times...

Comment: This question may be more suitable for CodeReview.SE

Comment: Take a look at the stuff that you are doing over en over again. Make a for loop with a counter in it. count to 11 and or 12 and then stop the loop.

Comment: I'm 100% agree with @RickBronger, it's your best solution :)

Comment: @RickBronger, could you please help me out?

Comment: [try something like this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://eval.in/670429
just make the key you want.

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
$new ['period_'.$i] = $periodic_items [$i];
}
var_dump($new);
```